# click buttons inside a form and click buttons outside a form get different results.

Tags: javascript

i have 5 blocks on top of the screen. i want to set the move speed and rotation speed of the first block with an form and the others are set with random numbers.
with the following code, if i click "start1" button(outside the form), all blocks rotate and fall down.
However if i click "start2" button(inside the form), all blocks do not move.
both buttons trigger the same function, but click button inside the form can't move and rotate these five blocks.
Can anybody kindly tell me the reason? sorry for my poor english.

```
<style>
    .block{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #b0{
        top:0px;
        left:100px;
        background-color:#0CC;
    }
    #b1{
        top:0px;
        left:250px;
        background-color:#FC0;
    }
    #b2{
        top:0px;
        left:400px;
        background-color:#F66;
    }
    #b3{
        top:0px;
        left:550px;
        background-color:#0CF;
    }
    #b4{
        top:0px;
        left:700px;
        background-color:#6C3;
    }
</style>
<script>    
    var play=false;
    var objs=[];   
    var speeds=[];    
    var rspeeds = []; 
    var pos =[];   
    var angle = [];  

    var move=function()
    {

        if(!play) return;

        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            if(pos[i]>700)  
            {
                pos[i]=0;   
                objs[i].style.top="0px";      

                if(i!=0)   
                {
                    speeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));
                    rspeeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                angle[i]=(angle[i]+ rspeeds[i] * 2)%360;  
                pos[i]=pos[i]+speeds[i];  

                objs[i].style.transform = "rotate("+ angle[i]+ "deg)"; 
                objs[i].style.top=pos[i]+"px";

            }
        }
    }

    function mystart()
    {
        objs[0]=document.getElementById("b0");     
        speeds[0]=parseInt(myform.speed.value);    
        rspeeds[0]=parseInt(myform.rspeed.value);  

        pos[0]=0;    
        angle[0]=0;  

        for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            var obj="b"+i;
            objs[i]=document.getElementById(obj);
            speeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));   
            rspeeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));  
            pos[i]=0;   
            angle[i]=0; 
        }
        play = true;

    }

    function mystop()
    {
        play=false;
        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            objs[i].style.top="0px";            
        }
    }   
    setInterval(move, 10);          

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="block" id="b0"></div>
<div class="block" id="b1"></div>
<div class="block" id="b2"></div>
<div class="block" id="b3"></div>
<div class="block" id="b4"></div>


<button onclick="mystart()"> start1 </button> <br />
<button onclick="mystop()" > stop1  </button> <br />
<form name="myform">
    speed:
    <input type="text" name="speed"  value="5" size="5" /> <br />
    rspeed:
    <input type="text" name="rspeed" value="2" size="5"  /> <br />
    <button onclick="mystart()"> start2 </button> <br />
    <button onclick="mystop()" > stop2  </button> <br />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try

`<button type="button"  onclick="mystart()"> start2 </button>`

Comment: Your second `buttons` are wrapped inside `form` hence it makes `form submit` action. Either use `event.preventDefault()` or `type='button'` or remove `form` wrapper!

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working fine. I've tried it in both Chrome and IE11. Here is a demo:

```html
<style>
    .block{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #b0{
        top:0px;
        left:100px;
        background-color:#0CC;
    }
    #b1{
        top:0px;
        left:250px;
        background-color:#FC0;
    }
    #b2{
        top:0px;
        left:400px;
        background-color:#F66;
    }
    #b3{
        top:0px;
        left:550px;
        background-color:#0CF;
    }
    #b4{
        top:0px;
        left:700px;
        background-color:#6C3;
    }
</style>
<script>    
    var play=false;
    var objs=[];   
    var speeds=[];    
    var rspeeds = []; 
    var pos =[];   
    var angle = [];  

    var move=function()
    {

        if(!play) return;

        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            if(pos[i]>700)  
            {
                pos[i]=0;   
                objs[i].style.top="0px";      

                if(i!=0)   
                {
                    speeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));
                    rspeeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                angle[i]=(angle[i]+ rspeeds[i] * 2)%360;  
                pos[i]=pos[i]+speeds[i];  

                objs[i].style.transform = "rotate("+ angle[i]+ "deg)"; 
                objs[i].style.top=pos[i]+"px";

            }
        }
    }

    function mystart()
    {
        objs[0]=document.getElementById("b0");     
        speeds[0]=parseInt(myform.speed.value);    
        rspeeds[0]=parseInt(myform.rspeed.value);  

        pos[0]=0;    
        angle[0]=0;  

        for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            var obj="b"+i;
            objs[i]=document.getElementById(obj);
            speeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));   
            rspeeds[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*10+1));  
            pos[i]=0;   
            angle[i]=0; 
        }
        play = true;

    }

    function mystop()
    {
        play=false;
        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            objs[i].style.top="0px";            
        }
    }   
    setInterval(move, 10);          

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="block" id="b0"></div>
<div class="block" id="b1"></div>
<div class="block" id="b2"></div>
<div class="block" id="b3"></div>
<div class="block" id="b4"></div>


<button onclick="mystart()"> start1 </button> <br />
<button onclick="mystop()" > stop1  </button> <br />
<form name="myform">
    speed:
    <input type="text" name="speed"  value="5" size="5" /> <br />
    rspeed:
    <input type="text" name="rspeed" value="2" size="5"  /> <br />
    <button onclick="mystart()"> start2 </button> <br />
    <button onclick="mystop()" > stop2  </button> <br />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Racil Hilan， thank you for your quick answer. i try my code in chrome, the button2 can not work. yet in ie10, i must press button2 several times to make the blocks move and rotate. but in the demo you show me, my code works fine. This condition is really confuse me!!  my chrome is  the latest version.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the code that you provided here is working in both IE and Chrome. Perhaps in your project there is some more code that conflicts with this one. Why don't you start from this code, remove everything else, and then start adding them one by one so you find the one that is causing the issue.

Comment: i found the reason. the <button> tag in chrome has default type "submit".
so i change the type to "button", the code can work correctly in chrome.
thanks  everyone who ever paid attention to my question. especially to Racil Hilan.

Comment: I would use `<input type="button" />` instead.